# Remove-WmiObject is not working and also $profile.Delete()

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to delete user profiles in Powershell.

Till Yesterday all `Remove-WmiObject` were working properly.
But today they are not working.
Please check the command below:

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {
    ((!$_.Special) -and
    ($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\Administrator") -and
    ($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\UpdatusUser") -and
    ($_.LocalPath -eq "C:\Users\$user"))
} | Remove-WmiObject
```

I am getting the error below:

```
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], FileLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

I have also tried `$profile.Delete()` method. This isn't working either. I get method not found error.
I have also checked whether the profile is loaded or not.
I have also tried logging users off before deleting their profile.
I have also tried using `Remove-Cmiinstance`, but same result.

Comment: Regardless of what is going on with Remove-WmiObject - you should avoid `$profile` as a variable name since it is an automatic variable in PowerShell. See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` for more info.

Comment: Thanks but also I tried with other variable names, still its not working

Comment: You might have to run it in a foreach, something like `foreach($p in $profiles) { $p | Remove-WmiObject -WhatIf }` but it's hard to tell since you don't really show any of your code.

Comment: For help with your code: *show* your code.

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: This bit seems redundant: `Where {((!$_.Special) -and ($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\Administrator")  -and ($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\UpdatusUser") -and ($_.LocalPath -eq "C:\Users\$user"))}`. No clue what's in and how you get `$user` 
 to begin with but it would seem to me that you could replace that entire where clause with something like `where { $_.LocalPath -eq "C:\Users\$user" }` If you are targetting the profile for a very specific user account there really should be no need for the exclusions.

Comment: Sorry for the bad code. I am new to powershell. It will be helpfull if you can also give me solution for the above problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what's in `$user` and how do you set that variable to begin with?

Comment: $user is a variable which replaces name of the user i am targeting in the command

Comment: Is it only for one specific profile that it doesn't work?  Maybe you could try get-ciminstance and remove-ciminstance instead.  I've seen where the folder stays there with a couple appdata folders left, but I didn't get any exception.  Can you delete the profile through the system control panel?  What is the output before remove-wmiobject?

Comment: Still - code missing, I'd help you out but I think I've had enough of the guess work for one day.

Answer (score 0):

This error commonly happens if one of the users you're removing is logged in at the time, which includes if they're logged into a PowerShell session **-or-** a temporary profile. Since you can't use this to remove logged in users, it's important to **terminate all sessions first, **then run the command****. The following will also work:

```
$ProfileName = "SomeName";
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {
((!$_.Special) -and
($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\Administrator") -and
($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\UpdatusUser") -and
($_.LocalPath -eq "C:\Users\$ProfileName")) } | Remove-WMIObject
```

In this case, `$ProfileName` needs to match the username for the profile being removed. This is a common solution for damaged profiles where the user receives the "Temporary Profile" error regularly.